# NPM scripts - config variables and command substitution not working in package.json

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, git-bash, package.json

**Case 1:** variable name used instead of value

```
package.json:

{
  "name": "example",
  "config": {
    "url": "localhost/dev"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "browser-sync start --files \"./**/*, !.node_modules/, !src\" --proxy $npm_package_config_url"
  }
}
```

`$npm run watch` opens `http://localhost:3000/$npm_package_config_url` in the browser, instead of `http://localhost:3000/dev`

So, `$npm_package_config_url` is used as a string, not as a variable.

**Case 2:**  command substitution is not working

```
{ 
  { ... },
  "scripts": {
    "rm:all": "npm rm $(ls -1 node_modules | tr '/\\n' ' ')"
   }
}
```

Sub-command lists folders in node_modules.

Again, `npm run rm:all` does nothing, because `$(ls -1 node_modules | tr '/\\n' ' ')` is interpreted as a folder name.

ENV: windows 10 | npm 3.5.1 | node 4.2.2 | git-bash 2.6.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A bit late, but on Windows you need to use `%npm_package_config_url%`

There's a potential package that will "fix" this for you (i.e. give you a work-around) (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) that was referenced in one of the npm issue posts.

Comment: cross-env will help _setting_ environment variables cross platform, if you want to _use_ environment variables in your scripts in a cross platform way, use [cross-var](http://npm.im/cross-var)

Comment: you saved me so much time with this answer :)

Comment: does not work on windows 10, cmd and powershell tested

Comment: @silvos ,  this was Windows 10 that it worked on. Perhaps something else has changed since - can you add a more up to date answer if you work out the new solution?

Comment: @Robbie Found out, that there was a bug in NPM, that got fixed at version 7.7.0
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2731
Now it's working - thx

Comment: Nicely found. Thanks. I'll leave the answer here then as it looks still relevant.